# Can I have an interface in facade design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, facade

I want to know if I have a facade class, can I create an interface and have multiple implementations of the class.

E.g.:

```
interface IUserDetailFacade{}

public class UserDetailsFacade implements IUserDetailFacade{}

public class UserDetailsLdapFacade implements IUserDetailFacade{}
```

Comment: Not much to work on here, can you provide an example of your intent. The Facade pattern's purpose is to abstract complexity of multiple related systems of class hierarchy. So, I may be miss interpreting your question; however, while the facade is of course an abstraction in itself, it is ironically tailored to the specific subsystems you are trying wrangle. In that respect your question makes no sense, because it is like asking,'If I have a solution to a problem can I have another solution to the same problem using the same solution'. The circular logic is yours, I'm just pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can.

The example that you have shared isn't quite detailed for me to understand how one more layer of abstraction (the `interface` you want to create) fits in.

But let me give you an example where this would make sense.

> Example

Suppose you are creating an application that tests how efficiently different C++ compilers compile the same source code.

You can create `CppCompiler` as an `interface` to different facades, one each for each type of `CppCompiler`.

```
public interface CppCompiler {
    void compile(String sourceFile);
}
```

`TurboCppCompiler`, `BorlandCppCompiler`, `GccCppCompiler`, etc. are **facades** of a subsystem of classes which do different steps in the compilation like parsing, assembling, linking, etc. For example, `TurboCppCompiler` implementation would look something like this.

```
public class TurboCppCompiler implements CppCompiler {

    // .. private variables

    public TurboCppCompiler(TurboParser parser, TurboAssembler assembler, TurboLinker linker) {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.assembler = assembler;
        this.linker = linker;
    }

    public void compile(String sourceFile) {
        /* Compile the code Borland Cpp style using the subsystems Parser, Assembler, Linker */
    }
}
```

> Usage

You can create a factory method that gets a compiler (notice how the `CppCompiler` is used as a `return` type here)

```
public static CppCompiler createCppCompiler(CompilerType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case TURBO:
            return new TurboCppCompiler(new TurboParser(), new TurboAssembler(), new TurboLinker());
        case BORLAND:
            return new BorlandCppCompiler(new BorlandParser(), new BorlandAssembler(), new BorlandLinker());
        case GCC:
            return new GccCppCompiler(new GccParser(), new GccAssembler(), new GccLinker());
    }
    throw new AssertionError("unknown compiler type:" + type);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're in the right track, because other parts of your system will be coupled with abstractions (i.e. your façade interface) while you can guarantee that your system will work with multiple given implementations of the whole façade interface.